# How do I avoid infinite loop when using Redux state in useEffect dependency array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, infinite-loop, use-effect

I'm trying to figure out why my useEffect function ends up in an infinite loop.
I have two variables that are hooked into my Redux store:

```
const vehicles: AllVehiclesCollection = useSelector((state: ReduxState) => state.claims?.vehicles ?? {});
const properties: AllPropertiesCollection = useSelector((state: ReduxState) => state.claims?.properties ?? {});
```

and I have an action that is dispatched to the store that updates these only after a user clicks a button.

I have a useEffect that will trigger based on either of these variables changing.

```
useEffect(() => {
    let fullVehicleList: DropdownData[] = getFormattedVehicleListForDisplay();
    let fullPropertyList: DropdownData[] = getFormattedPropertyListForDisplay();
    let fullList = fullVehicleList.concat(fullPropertyList);
    if (fullList.length > 0) {
      setVehiclesAndPropertiesList(fullList);
    } else {
      setVehiclesAndPropertiesList(null);
    }
  }, [vehicles, properties]);
```

Nowhere in this code are the vehicles or properties variables changed or any actions dispatched that would change the Redux state.

getFormattedVehicleListForDisplay function:

```
const getFormattedVehicleListForDisplay = () => {
    let list: DropdownData[] = [];
    if (Object.keys(vehicles).length > 0) {
      let thisPolicysVehicles = [];
      if (vehicles !== null) {
        const key = `${selectedPolicy.symbol}${selectedPolicy.number}`;
        thisPolicysVehicles = vehicles[key];
      }
      if (thisPolicysVehicles && thisPolicysVehicles.length > 0) {
        thisPolicysVehicles.forEach((vehicle: VehicleInformation) => {
          if (vehicle.vehicleMake !== OTHER_VEHICLE) {
            list.push({
              label: formatVehicleForDisplay(vehicle),
              value: { ...vehicle, type: 'V' },
            });
          } else {
            list.push({ label: vehicle.vehicleMake, value: {} });
          }
        });
      }
    }
    return list;
  };
```

getFormattedPropertyListForDisplay function:

```
const getFormattedPropertyListForDisplay = () => {
    let list: DropdownDataOMIG[] = [];
    if (Object.keys(properties).length > 0) {
      let thisPolicysProperties = [];
      if (properties !== null) {
        const key = `${selectedPolicy.symbol}${selectedPolicy.number}`;
        thisPolicysProperties = properties[key];
      }
      if (thisPolicysProperties && thisPolicysProperties.length > 0) {
        thisPolicysProperties.forEach((property: LocationInformation) => {
          if (property.locStreet1 !== OTHER_PROP) {
            list.push({
              label: formatPropertyForDisplay(property),
              value: { ...property, type: 'P' },
            });
          } else {
            list.push({ label: property.locStreet1, value: {} });
          }
        });
      }
    }
    return list;
  };
```

For reference, the data in vehicles and properties is a set of key-value pairs where the key is a unique identifier of a given account number and the value is an array of vehicle/property objects for that account.

Any idea why this goes into an infinite loop when using Redux state in the dependency array? Is there a different way to use Redux state in a dependency array? Thanks!

Comment: there is too much code to see on your post, but you can always wrap the code on your `useEffect` with an `if` condition... also you can use `const prevState = React.useRef(prevStateValue)` and compare the previous state with the current state (you will need to dig more into this if you will use this approach).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using

```
const vehicles = useSelector((state: ReduxState) => state.claims?.vehicles ?? {});
```

Each time this is triggered, and you don't have `vehicles` in your store, you return a **new** object `{}`. and `{} === {} // false`

So ain your `useEffect` dependency array, it's each time a new Object, so useEffect is triggered.

So either remove your  `|| {}` in your selector (because `null === null` & `undefined === undefined`) or consider moving to `useShallowSelector` as explained in [react-redux documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#equality-comparisons-and-updates)